# Apply Setter to Style's trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have XAML with triggers like this:

```
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visible}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=AnimationEnabled}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.000"
                                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.200"
                                                    From="0,570,0,-570" To="0,0,0,-1">
                                    <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </ThicknessAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.200"
                                                    From="0,0,0,0" To="0,570,0,-570">
                                    <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </ThicknessAnimation>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.200" 
                                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visible}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=AnimationEnabled}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Visible}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=AnimationEnabled}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,570,0,-570" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```

The idea is that if animation is enabled I'm showing animation.
But if it's not, I want simply move or make things visible/hidden instead animation.

And my example is not working. I assume this is because I haven't declared TargetName for Setter. But I don't wan't to do this because I want my properties be applied the same was as Style is.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does the animation play but not the "simple" setters work? Does nothing happen? Did you check that your property changes are actually notifying the GUI?

Comment: Yep, nothing happens for "simple" setters. Property changes are notifying GUI.